# nodejs won't let me change directory or even make a new one

Tags: node.js, directory

pretty much as the image shows, am getting weird syntax errors on everything. am very new to all this but trying my hardest to learn for charity, please help.

am trying to link to an attempted chat bot tried running "cd d:\justgivingbot\app.js" and everything in between. 
shown below are other attempted entries, slashes in all directions. mkdir doesn't run either

[image: Attempted Node]

Comment: When you are in the Node REPL, you can't type in shell commands like `cd` or `ls`. Node is a javascript runtime, it expects javascript input.

Comment: It looks like your question is incomplete. You are mentioning an image, which I can't see in the post (note that code should be posted as text, not in the form of images), and then there's "shown below" but there is no further content below that sentence...

Comment: You need to use the built in file system api (fs) if you want to do shell-like commands. Documentation is here https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdir_path_mode_callback. Not much information given so it's difficult to tell if this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by using 'Child Process' build-in module to execute external commands like as 'mkdir' and here is Node.js code which do this:

```
var folderName = 'test';
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('mkdir '+folderName, function (err, stdOut, stdErr){if(!err){console.log('Folder created successfully');} else{console.log(stdErr);}});
```

Comment: No reason to launch a shell to create a directory.  It's built right into node.js: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdir_path_mode_callback

Comment: That's right for create directory example, but I added this solution to execute any external commands in general.

Comment: I don't think this is really what the OP wants.  They're just confused about the node prompt vs. the system prompt.